# How to implement such pop over view animation?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, alert

I was using this ride-sharing ios app and found this pop over animation of options view. I wanted to implement similar pop over but could figure out if it is a custom transition or animation? [Here is a link to the GIF of popover in application.](https://github.com/PrabhakarThapa362/videograb/blob/master/IMG_8984.GIF)

It will be helpful to link me to examples/tutorial/code with similar animation so that I can begin implementing on my ios app.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple.  Just position your options view on the screen where you want it to appear and set the alpha to 0 so it is hidden.  Then, prior to animation, make the view wider using scaleX, and translate it down using translationY.  Then simply animate it back to .identity and animate the alpha back to 1.0 so it fades in. A basic example is below.  When you dismiss the view you just do the opposite.  Let me know if you need help with that.

```
    yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 0)
    yourView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0.0, y: 200.0)
    yourView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        yourView.transform = .identity
        yourView.alpha = 1.0
                          })
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the following animation using leading, trailing and button constraints. Please let me know if such animation can be done in other ways.

```
    yourview.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, animations: {
        self.leadingConstraints.constant = 20
        self.trailConstraints.constant = -20
        self.buttonConstraints.constant = 20
        self.yourview.alpha = 1
        self.yourview.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
```